# Formik + yup not displaying errors

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have the following form:

```
import React from 'react'
import PanelInputField from './form_components/panel_input_field'
import * as yup from 'yup'
import { withFormik, FormikErrors, FormikProps } from "formik";

const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  length: yup
    .number()
    .min(200, 'NOT BIG ENOUGH')
    .required()
})

class SpecificationsForm extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {
      values,
      handleInputChange,
      handleSelectChange,
      touched,
      errors
    } = this.props;

    console.log(errors)
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default specifications-panel" id="js-turbosquid-product-specifications-panel">
        <div className="panel-heading">
          <a href="#" className="js-more-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#specifications-panel-instructions" tabIndex="-1">
            Specifications
            <i className="fa fa-question-circle" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className="panel-body panel-collapse collapse in" id="specification-panel-body">
          <div className="panel-body-container">
            <div id="specifications-panel-instructions" className="panel-instructions collapse" />

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-6">

                <PanelInputField 
                  label='Length'
                  value={ values.length }
                  onChange={ handleInputChange } 
                  formName='turbosquid_product_form_length'
                  fieldName='length'
                />
                <div className="form-field-error">{errors.length ? errors.length : "No Error"}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ProductSpecificationsMotionCapturePanel = withFormik({
  validationSchema,
  enableReinitialize: true,
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => (props),
  handleInputChange: (props) => (props.handleInputChange),
  handleSelectChange: (props) => (props.handleSelectChange),
})(SpecificationsForm)

export default ProductSpecificationsMotionCapturePanel
```

The form works properly, it is displayed and everything but I can't seem to make formik see the errors. In this example I have the length field with integer values. Whenever I input something, the validations work (the `console.log` prints) but the object is totally empty.

Even if I write non numbers in the input, no errors are displayed ever.

Does anyone have a suggestion on what I could do to make it work?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/67606619/5220683

Answer (score 6):

Did you setup initial values? It looks like you did not in this file. If not, try setting that up and see if it works.

Comment: Additionally, you can't set `initialValues` to an empty object (e.g. `const initialValues = {};`). You have to include an initial value for the field name you want to error to show for. For example, `const initialValues = { name: '' };` for no initial value for name.